# Store byte of an int in MIPS

Tags: mips

I am using PCSpim and I have a problem
I have an array of characters for inserting the value of hexadecimal number, call it HEXARRAY.

HEXARRAY: .byte '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'.

and I want to insert an integer by doing

sb $t0, HEXARRAY($t1)

where $t0 is the int I want, lets say 8.
and $t1 is 8, the last byte in the array.

int has 4 bytes in MIPS, how can I insert the int to 1 byte?

Comment: Can you be clearer? What's with `sb $t0, HEXARRAY($t1)` that is not working?

Comment: sb stores byte only, which means 1 byte, and integer is 4 bytes, how can i fit in the 4 bytes, into this 1 byte, where my integer only requires 1 byte (between 127 and -128)

Comment: Bits (and so are Bytes) are a measurement unit. Asking to fit 4 bytes into 1 bytes is like asking to fit 4 Litres of water into 1 Litre of water. You can't do that without throwing away some of it. That's the same with your question, which is why I asked for a clarification. `sb` stores only the least significant byte (throwing away the other 3 bytes), so if any possible number in `$t0` is within 0-255 or -128-127 (which are ranges that require only 1 byte) then you can use `sb` without any problem. If that's not the case you have to tell use which "water" to throw away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a word (32 bits) by doing 'sw' = store word... something like:

```
number:   .word 8      # your number is 8
space:    .space 20    # adress to save your number

la $t3, number         # loading the adress of your number 8
lw $t3, 0($t3)         # NOTICE that with 'lw' you are taking your WHOLE WORD = number 8

la $s1, space
sw $t3, 0($s1)         # where $t3 is your number and $s1 the adress you want to save it
```

If you don't want to save the entire number 8, but save separate bytes of your number... you can do it in diferent adresses of $s1.

Something like:

```
sb $t3, 0($s1)    # you are storing the byte'00001000' in the 1st adress of $s1
addi $s1, $s1, 1  # adding 1 to the adress where you want to save your next byte
srl $t3, $t3, 3   # moving your number 8 (in binary) to the right... so you can
                  # 'sb' = store byte (a different one) again in $s1
```